# Filling in nans for numbers in a column-specific way

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, apply

Given a `DataFrame` and a `list` of indexes, is there an efficient `pandas` function that put `nan` value for all values vertically preceeding each of the entries of the list?

For example, suppose we have the list `[4,8]` and the following `DataFrame`:

```
index     0      1
5         1      2
2         9      3 
4         3.2    3
8         9      8.7
```

The desired output is simply:

```
index     0        1
5         nan      nan
2         nan      nan 
4         3.2      nan
8         9        8.7
```

Any suggestions for such a function that does this fast?

Comment: Is that `index` a column or the index of the dataframe?

Comment: It's the index of the dataframe

Comment: Could you add code to create that sample `df`?

Comment: I should have added it, bit in the answer below it had already been reproduced. Will add in question next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one NumPy approach based on [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
s = [4,8]

a = df.values
idx = df.index.values
sidx = np.argsort(idx)
matching_row_indx = sidx[np.searchsorted(idx, s, sorter = sidx)]
mask = np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None] < matching_row_indx
a[mask] = np.nan
```

Sample run -

```
In [107]: df
Out[107]: 
         0    1
index          
5      1.0  2.0
2      9.0  3.0
4      3.2  3.0
8      9.0  8.7

In [108]: s = [4,8]

In [109]: a = df.values
     ...: idx = df.index.values
     ...: sidx = np.argsort(idx)
     ...: matching_row_indx = sidx[np.searchsorted(idx, s, sorter = sidx)]
     ...: mask = np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None] < matching_row_indx
     ...: a[mask] = np.nan
     ...: 

In [110]: df
Out[110]: 
         0    1
index          
5      NaN  NaN
2      NaN  NaN
4      3.2  NaN
8      9.0  8.7
```

Answer (score 1):

It was a bit tricky to recreate your example but this should do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'index': [5, 2, 4, 8], 0: [1, 9, 3.2, 9], 1: [2, 3, 3, 8.7]})
df.set_index('index', inplace=True)
for i, item in enumerate([4,8]):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if index != item:
            row[i] = np.nan
        else:
            break
```